No python3 provider found
When I try to run a Pyhton expression, I get that there is not python provider:
:lua vim.fn.py3eval("2+2")                                                                                                               
E5108: Error executing lua Vim:E319: No "python3" provider found. Run ":checkhealth provider"                                            
stack traceback:                                                                                                                         
        [C]: in function 'py3eval'                                                                                                       
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk

However there is.
Here is the output of :checkhealth provider.python:
provider.python: require("provider.python.health").check()                                                                           
                                                                                                                                        
 Python 3 provider (optional)                                                                                                         
 - pyenv: Path: /usr/share/pyenv/libexec/pyenv                                                                                        
 - pyenv: Root: /home/USERNAME/.pyenv                                                                                                 
 - Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/home/USERNAME/.pyenv/versions/neovim/bin/python3"                                                   
 - Executable: /home/USERNAME/.pyenv/versions/neovim/bin/python3                                                                      
 - Python version: 3.11.7                                                                                                             
 - pynvim version: 0.5.0                                                                                                              
 - OK Latest pynvim is installed.                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                       
 Python virtualenv                                                                                                                    
 - OK no $VIRTUAL_ENV                                               


Perhaps a bug report to the Neovim devs will get you further on this one; as is, it would seem difficult to figure out what's "gone wrong" here

Does pyxeval() or pyeval() work? What about :python3 ? Also mention your exact Nvim version.

Both pyxeval and pyeval gives the same error. :python3 gives the same error (no provider found). nvim v0.10.1
